# Instance method inheritance

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

Is there a way to declare inheritance for a method of an instance.

```
//SOME CLASS
class SomeClass{
    someMethod{
        //SOMETHING HAPPENS
    }
}
function myComponent(){
    this.subcomponents={
        popup:function(){
            //SOMETHING HAPPENS
        }
    }
    this.init=()=>{
        //NEW INSTANCE OF SUBCOMPONENT POPUP
        var popup = new this.subcomponents.popup();
        //DESIRED RESULT WOULD BE ABLE TO CALL
        popup.someMethod();
    }
}
//myComponent inherits someMethod()
myComponent.prototype = new SomeClass();
//IS THERE ANYWAY TO ASSIGN INHERITANCE TO SUBMETHODS OF AN INSTANCE 
myComponent.subcomponents.popup.prototype = new SomeClass();
```

Desired output would be to have the new instance of the method `popup` with inheritance of `SomeClass` so I would be able to call `popup.someMethod()`.

**Question:** How can I assign `popup` method, inheritance of `SomeClass` so I could call `popup.someMethod()`?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to somehow use the someMethod function in SomeClass and apply that to popup. In order to do that you don't need to mess with prototype chains and inheritance.

Ie

```
SomeClass.prototype.someMethod.call(popup, arguments)
```

This will take someMethod, and change the value of 'this' to popup and execute it with whatever arguments you provide

Comment: I'm not trying to do that at all. I'm actually trying to do `popup.someMethod()` or `popup.whatevermethodfromtheinheritedclass()`

Comment: since you're using es6, why don't you make popup a separate class that extends SomeClass?

Comment: I mean either ES5 or ES6 exact same thing... but yes currently only way I know would be to make separate classes. There are a lot of times where the classes are so small and only relative to a parent class and they should really be managed as a sub-component or sub-class of the parent, so thats what I'm looking for a way to do.